# C# Class constructor that can take type int OR float

Tags: unity-game-engine, c#-8.0

I would like to have a class Stat be able to take in `(int value)` or `(float value)`

The reason for this being that I want to create a `Dictionary(string, Stat)` so I can't make two classes. I also have functions in the class for levelling up and resetting the stat, so I can't make multiple constructors.

I can edit in my code if it would help, but I believe I have described the issue well enough.
I am using Unity so I am locked at C# version 8.0

Edit: If this seems like a stupid question I apologise. I am entirely self taught so I don't know some stuff. Also I did do a lot of searching before posting this question, but there were no solutions that I could find.

Edit(2):
My question was unclear. My end goal is something like this:

```
Dictionary stats = new Dictionary(string, Stat)
{
    {"health", Stat(int 30)}
    {"attack", Stat(float 2.5)}
    ...
}
```

A list of stats that can be either int or float, for the sake of performance.

Comment: *"so I can't make two classes"* - you could make `Stat` and interface or (abstract) base class and have two classes that inherit from it. That may (or may not) be the solution you are looking for. It's a bit unclear though how exactly you intend to use this class and how the `int` and `float` constructors play into it

Comment: I plan to have a dictionary of types string and Stat. I wanted to be able to use int and float for the sake of performance. If every stat is a float performance is gonna suffer.
If Dictionary(string, Stat) would it be able to take in classes that inherited from Stat?

Comment: *"If every stat is a float performance is gonna suffer."* - how many stats do you have that this would be a problem? And how did you measure that this is indeed the case? You'd need some quite extreme numbers for the floating point performance to become a real bottleneck

Comment: That was a comment my friend had made, someone with more programming experience than I. Or to some degree he wasn't happy with all stats being floats.
You think just making them all floats would be fine? That would make my life easier.

Separate of that any ideas on how someone would achieve my goal? I'm curious if it's even possible.

Oh also the stats are meant to grow a lot, due to a powerup system the game will have.

Comment: In none of the games I have worked on the stats system was ever a bottleneck. Discussions of `float` vs `int` performance only make sense in systems that have to perform *a lot* of calculations. And we never used a `Dictionary` to store the stats either, just a `class` with the types of stats being member fields makes a lot more sense, since the stats have to be defined all throughout code to be useful anyway

Comment: This has been a very useful discussion. You have described my original design. My friend was unhappy with my design saying it could cause issues, but it seems my system was fine. Thank you for your time. I will close down this question now.

Comment: _"am using Unity so I am locked at C# version 8.0"_ - if you are already making pre-compiled .NET assemblies and dropping the result into Unity as Managed Plugins then you can take it one step further and modify the external .NET project to use C# 10 via `<LangVersion>10.0</LangVersion>`.  To Unity it still appears as a .NET Standard 2.1/Core 3 compliant DLL.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version#defaults

Answer (score -1, accepted):

---

The answer was simple. Thanks to @UnholySheep for discussing this with me.  This answer is a summary of the comments beneath the question **above** (saved here in the event they are deleted).

---

UnholySheep:

> you could make Stat and interface or (abstract) base class and have two classes that inherit from it.

Concerns over performance most likely don't apply, again from Mr Sheep:

> You'd need some quite extreme numbers for the floating point performance to become a real bottleneck

> In none of the games I have worked on the stats system was ever a bottleneck. Discussions of float vs int performance only make sense in systems that have to perform a lot of calculations.

As for class design vs dictionaries, a simple class with embedded fields will suffice:

> we never used a Dictionary to store the stats either, just a class with the types of stats being member fields makes a lot more sense, since the stats have to be defined all throughout code to be useful anyway

Comment: Ah, the classic XY problem.

Comment: @MickyD I hope that edit clears some things up. In summary I am dumb and my question was stupid. The best path was just to do my original idea and use floats for all my stats. Everything I said I wanted to do in the original question was completely unneeded and overcomplicated. Also I edited out anything mentioning a dictionary because it wasn't relevant to the problem.

Comment: Thanks @Caino.  I hope you don't mind but I have edited your answer.  Previously it read as a _diary_ about _what had transpired without actually saying what the solution was._  There was no mention of creating a class with member fields to use for stats.  You did mention your original idea for a class but the answer gave the impression this wasn't the way to go.  Also, I think you are putting yourself down - your question wasn't _"pointless"_ nor r u dumb because readers as well as yourself learnt something.  Remember - _we are, all, learning something, somewhere, sometime._ Well done. +1  :)